# My Navigation Roll-over menu bar is not working

Tags: html, css, navbar

I can't get my nav bar to roll over the main content. Here is a link to my site: http://www.nourishandinspireblog.com/nourishandinspire/ please ignore the header as I have not decided on the position I'll have it in.

Comment: What do you mean by 'roll over'?

Comment: I actually should have said dropdown menu instead of rollover. This is the site I was using the code from which has an example of what I was trying to create with my nav bar: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 #nav ul ul {left: 9999px;position: absolute;}
 #nav ul li:hover ul{left: 0;}
```

this may help you
http://jsfiddle.net/r8Ez4/

Comment: should i get rid of all my nav bar code in the CSS and only use this:  #nav ul ul {left: 9999px;position: absolute;}
 #nav ul li:hover ul{left: 0;}

Comment: yes, use this : #nav ul ul {left: 9999px;position: absolute;}
 #nav ul li:hover ul{left: 0;} 
instance of #nav ul ul{display:none} 
or you can check my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r8Ez4/

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. now it has zero drop down menus it was actually doing less then I already had. this what i was trying to achieve: line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: remove this code #nav ul ul{display:none}  from line number 52

Comment: also add this #nav ul ul {left: 9999px;position: absolute;}
 #nav ul li:hover ul{left: 0;}

Comment: sorry i forgot #nav ul li{position: relative;}
please add this too

Comment: i'm still confused. what code should i have in my css for my nav bar? with what you told me to take out and add it's giving me more problems than i previously had

Comment: I did this and no drop down meuns appear. This code does not fix my problem

Comment: check this all is your code here http://jsfiddle.net/5WU6z/1/
just make #nav ul li:hover ul{left: 47px}

Comment: it's still not working. i'm going to ask again. do i take out ALL of my nav bar code and JUST add this code.maybe i need to keep some of my coding?  ul {padding: 0;}
#nav ul ul{top: 0 important!;}
    #nav ul li{ float: left; list-style: none;margin-right: 10px;position: relative;display: block; } 
#nav ul li a{background: #ccc;padding: 5px;}
    #nav ul ul {left: 9999px;position: absolute;}
#nav ul li:hover ul{left: 0;}
#nav ul:hover ul{
background: #070700;
border-radius: 0px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 48px;
z-index: 999;}

Answer (score 0):

The code will look like this

```
#nav ul li{position: relative;}
#nav ul ul {left: 9999px;position: absolute;}
#nav ul li:hover ul{left: 0;}
```

forgot to mention `#nav ul li{position: relative;}`
try this now this will be work for you

remove this code `#nav ul ul{display:none}` and `top: 100%;` in `#nav ul ul`